# MySQL copy values of one column to another column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- `t1(mainid, parentid)`
- `t2(mainid, parentid)`

How would I copy the values of `t1.mainid` to `t2.parentid`?

I tried using:

```
SELECT mainid INTO t2 FROM t1
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Do you want to make new rows or update already existing rows?

Comment: I want to create new rows in table2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO t2(parentid) SELECT mainid FROM t1
```

Answer (score 2):

In case the mainid in t2 is also auto increment

```
INSERT INTO t2(parentid) SELECT mainid FROM t1
```

Comment: t2`s mainid IS autoincremented.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT 0,mainid FROM t1
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not seem to work. I forgot to mention, that the values, which I want to copy from t1 are primary keys(auto incremented).

Comment: It works also if t2 uses `AUTO_INCREMENT` - the 0 will be simply replaced by the next increment.

Comment: What does `SELECT 0,mainid FROM t1` give?

Comment: what @EugenRieck meant is "do you have records in t1"

Answer (score 1):

The following solution

```
INSERT INTO t2(parentid) SELECT mainid FROM t1
```

will work, as long as t2(mainid) has a default value set. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO tbl_name [(col_name,...)] SELECT ....`

[`INSERT-SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you insert into a table, you have to think about the fact that you are inserting an entire row in the table, not just the value of one column. Even if some of the columns have default values, it is helpful to think about inserting an entire row into a table.

So to cross the mainid column's values from t1 into t2's parentid column, you could do the following:

```
INSERT INTO T2 SELECT 0,mainid FROM T1
```

But for every mainid value in T1, you will transfer a 0 and the manid value to make up 
a t2 row. If t2 has a unique constraint, you won't be able to solve the problem this way.